# Object Model version of stsadm -o execsvcadmjobs command

Tags: c#, sharepoint, deployment, stsadm

What is the equivalent command to perform any outstanding actions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quiet complex series of commands which starts off by calling a method on an internal static class (SPTimerStore), so in order to reproduce it you'll have to reproduce at least also this method.

If you really want to see what's going on you can open stsadm.exe in [.Net Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com) it has a class for each of the out-of-the-box operations where the run method is the one called at execution time

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit complicated, the easiest way for this command is: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/517c92c8-ebe5-42c7-bfb3-bde0c12fda2f/
but the .net reflector is worthy of a mention.